# Using sound on a website for iPhone, BlackBerry and Android

Tags: android, blackberry, html, audio

I am developing a website that will play sound files for all smartphone users -- BlackBerry, Android, and iPhone.  I've already figured this out for the iPhone, but how do I do this for BlackBerry and Android?

Comment: You might want to consider Nokia Symbian as part of 'all smartphone users'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the HTML5 Audio Tag, I beliebe it is supported on all those device browsers